# Dim macbook screen when connected to external monitor?

Tags: mac

Im connecting my mac laptop to an external display (A mac pc via the thunderbolt cable). If I use the keyboard key to dim the display it happens on the external monitor not the laptop screen. How can I lower the brightness on the laptop screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does pressing the brightness keys while holding control work?

When I used a MacBook Air with a Thunderbolt Display, the brightness keys applied to the laptop display when I didn't hold control and to the Thunderbold Display when I did hold control.